# IIS Automatic recycle on app sometimes does not start the app

Tags: iis

we've come across a weird issue, I've seen some similar posts here but none of them had any solution that would work, that's why I have decided to submit my own question.

[same issue 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/154088/can-iis-automatic-recycle-fail-or-timeout)

[kind of similar but no app issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212765/asp-net-mvc-3-application-failing-randomly-upon-application-pool-recycle)

We have an application on a server that other applications use to connect to the SAP environment (provides calls to SAP system). It has it's own application pool and published application with automatic recycles at 6AM, 2PM and 10PM, it is set to Always running, Suspend and so on. The log of the service has no erros - just a big gap between the failed automatic recycle and the manual one, other apps are having app timeout problems, event viewer seems to not have any helpful information.
The problem occured when we published this app on another server, we set up the IIS in the same way but what has started happening is that some of the automatic recycles do not go through - the application stops working and is required to be manually recycled (or we put in an app_offline.html file for a split second) to resolve the issue. Other applications are attempting to communicate with this API service (even with just a PING every 5sec) but are getting timed out. As you can imagine this is quite troublesome for apps in production to not be able to communicate and us having to check whether the planned automatic recycle was able to start again.

What's even worse is that there is yet another server where we've just published the app as well and there it has been working without any issues.

Has anyone faced similar issue or might know how to resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Compare the applicationhost.config files of the working/non working machines. Could be something subtle like the order modules are loading could cause it to trip up sometimes? Ensure the app pool declaration has `startMode="AlwaysRunning"` and site has `preloadEnabled="true"`. You could enable Application Initilization is IIS so you specify a url that correctly initilizes your app before the app pool receives other traffic. Check the HTTPERR log too - some low level errors dont end up in Event Viewer. Enabling Failed request tracing might catch something too? Is the PING an ICMP or API call?

Comment: Does this problem occur intermittently on new servers? In the current situation, I think all you can do is look for any error messages and related logs about when this error occurred to narrow down the problem. Try checking the new server CPU, memory, disk I/O, and network usage, or adjusting the automatic recycling frequency to see if that affects the problem?